# Unable to download updates: The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, updates, dependencies, update-manager

Ubuntu 21.04 64 bits

The warning window doesn't show what software has the problem.

[image: Software Center screenshot]

I typed `sudo apt-get update` showing this:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [115 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease [101 kB] 
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute InRelease 
Fetched 326 kB in 5s (61.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: First, restart the computer and see if you still get the issue. Second, if the error persists, what package are you trying to install?

Comment: Just wanted to update as always do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Run the following commands to update the packages manually:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

The first command only updates your package list to let the system know what packages need to be updated. The second command actually performs the upgrade (software updates).

**Alternatively, you could also run the following commands to achieve the exact same result:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

**On a related note, you can skip kernel updates by running the following commands instead (not recommended):**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

---

**If it still shows the same message in the software center, run the following command to update vim manually:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall vim
```

Comment: The first pair of commands worked. I restarted the laptop and open the Software app. A larger list of updates appeared and updated. Thank you.